# Typescript event emitter typings

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm implementing `event emitter` but ran into a problem with typescript typing. Please tell me how to make this work.

```
export type IEventMap = {
    "mount": () => void;
    "mounted": () => void;
    "unmount": () => void;
    "unmounted": () => void;
    "test1": (stringArg: string) => void;
    "test2": (numberArg: number) => void;
};

export type IEventNames = keyof IEventMap;
export type IEventFn<K extends IEventNames> = IEventMap[K];
export type IEventListeners = { [K in IEventNames]?: Set<IEventFn<K>> };

export default class Events {

    private readonly listeners: IEventListeners = {};

    public on <K extends IEventNames> (eventName: K, callback: IEventFn<K>) {

        if (!this.listeners[eventName]) {
            this.listeners[eventName] = new Set();
        }

        this.listeners[eventName].add(callback);

    }

    public off <K extends IEventNames> (eventName: K, callback: IEventFn<K>) {

        if (this.listeners[eventName]) {
            this.listeners[eventName].delete(callback);
        }

    }

    public emit <K extends IEventNames> (eventName: K, ...args: Parameters<IEventFn<K>>) {

        if (this.listeners[eventName]) {
            this.listeners[eventName].forEach(callback => callback(...args));
        }

    }

}

// test

const events = new Events();

events.on("mount", () => {
    console.log("mount");
});

events.on("test1", arg => {
    console.log(arg);
});

events.on("test2", arg => {
    console.log(arg);
});

events.emit("mount");
events.emit("test1", "test string");
events.emit("test2", 1);
```

Errors

> Type 'Set<IEventFn>' is not assignable to type
> 'IEventListeners[K]'.   Type 'Set<IEventFn>' is not assignable to
> type 'Set<() => void> & Set<() => void> & Set<() => void> & Set<() =>
> void> & Set<(stringArg: string) => void> & Set<(numberArg: number) =>
> void>'.
> Type 'Set<IEventFn>' is not assignable to type 'Set<() => void>'.
> Type 'IEventFn' is not assignable to type '() => void'.
> Type '(() => void) | (() => void) | (() => void) | (() => void) | ((stringArg: string) => void) | ((numberArg: number) => void)'
> is not assignable to type '() => void'.
> Type '(stringArg: string) => void' is not assignable to type '() => void'.

> Object is possibly 'undefined'. Object is possibly 'undefined'. Object
> is possibly 'undefined'.

> A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest
> parameter.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.0-dev.20221015#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCSBRAbsAdjAWQEMw4BeOAbwCgBIAIgFsIBXfegLjgAoBKcgHxwsEAJYATANx0mrfMHGce-MkJETpDNszYwlfQcLFSZ2uTAX6Va45voWAzjACM%20p1FG4A5gEEoXrndPL2sjDRlHGAAmfVwWRgAjYCg-ALg4xOTQ9RMAX2lqUEhYBGRUTBx8ADkiRmAHcjgAa2BECAAzdGw8QhJpIuh4JBQuypgAMVwAHgBpOFALXHEGip6auochClX8YjAAbRmAXX7wQdKRnZgAGVEnPGSGiko4Q7hPUbXa%20qOAfi4AMrAGBTK6TWYCIT5aiFM4lcTAdpEFgAG3gAGMUUQHA1uvgGjQ6GAPFgiBY4FBgERxBBcCjEHAUXdFo8uFdbvdcI9GpRoUSWAkmei4LS4LN5iBFstPtVvpseMAxutgFwZgAaODoogolEJIjoppsvETaYzAT8Qm0WiiTrcACEMAAFncAHRMzmPfaKr51I4WuhWp2u90sqAOL1K75HRpcgDucCBMD4mlouRhgedDjdzIeYYjPuARxd1PE3C1Or1Bt4BVT6bAAqFIvanXFCzw0quyvl3G9srqqo15d1%20sNMpNEP9AZtPCDWZDufDvZgyr9VADtFn2Y9eaXK5dCJRwOAZe1w6rKbTdEvtHrgtEwuAjFE8FbkvbK2NXaEPcj-bg6rgF0gKIfwHC4AAFEDvgsMNQWNcEzXNNcp1tTd5y5Hdf0Lf0rQ3TMt1DRcsKLdpoAwfVHRPCsR0MIdKyabggOLUDeGrANr0vS8AHouIQeoYBhdFaSceYxiedJgHjY0HGTGElyzWluFkXR6A1AxVDXWghNwBwIEPN0IC8JSdHYNjcjYwoxJdRT7H41wNRArxDBoLThL04ADKMxyzIs%20TrNwJTIhiBz-GcuhtN0-SUUM7hvOkcyCj8x9n2M8x6DYpKnyTWynHsuAcvgIJvHS-orOS7KgtUuBnGrIA)

Comment: There are broadly unrelated two problems with your code; one is the correlation between `eventName` and `callback` or `args` and the compiler's inability to see it.  The other is the "possibly `undefined`" happening after you set a property. As such, this question, as asked, isn't focused enough.  If I fix both issues I get [this](//tsplay.dev/wRXB7m).  I'd be happy to write up an answer, but I'd appreciate it if you [edit] this question to make just *one* of these issues primary (and remove the other problem), and if you want to see the other addressed you open a new question for it.

Comment: For example, assuming correlation is your primary issue, could you change your code to [this](https://tsplay.dev/NVb3lN) so we don't have to spend time talking about "possibly `undefined`?  If you want to hear an explanation for the `undefined` issue that would belong in a new q/a pair.  (Conversely, if `undefined` is your primary issue, could oyu change your code to [this](https://tsplay.dev/WoA8MN) so we don't have to spend time talking about correlation? etc) Anyway, let me know how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. interchangeable callbacks should actually be rest-args, so

```
export type IEventFn<K extends IEventNames> = (...a: Parameters<IEventMap[K]>) => void;
```

fixes half of errors

2. ts doesn't remember type if if by whatever reason, just use `?.`

```
this.listeners[eventName]?.delete(callback);
```

3. ts doesn't want do assign mismatching types, type down so types match

```
let l: { [KK in K]?: Set<IEventFn<KK>> } = this.listeners;
(l[eventName] ??= new Set<IEventFn<K>>()).add(callback);
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.0-dev.20221015#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCSBRAbsAdjAWQEMw4BeOAbwCgBIAIgFsIBXfegLjgAoBKcgHxwsEAJYATANx0mrfMHGce-MkJETpDNszYwlfQcLFSZ2uTAX6Va45voWAzjACM%20p1FG4A5gEEoXrndPL2sjDRlHGAAmfVwWRgAjYCg-ALg4xOTQ9RMAX2lqUEhYBGRUTBx8ADkiRmAHcjgAa2BECAAzdGw8QhJpIuh4JBQuypgAMVwAHgBpOFALXHEGip6auochCm4AOj2iLgAFIiha4AsoBynV-GIwAG0ZgF0BbNtC8EHSkZuYABlRE48MkGhRKHBHnBPKM1mcHE8APxcADK52u3Xwk1mAiE%20WoH2K8HEwHaRBYABt4ABjclEBwNDEwBo0OhgDxYIgWOBQYBEcQQXDkxBwcmAxYgri-AFA3AgxqUPG0MAsBKiqlwAWzeYgRbLGHVOECbjAMbrYBcGYAGjgVKI5PJCSIVKaksZWJmryodFo5POIq44Mec2hzyRcFRMHRY3dHtxjRgAAtATtRTKQZpaNxyfcTbC6k84AiERRZQB3cNo37unF8Xg7Pnibi2%202O528TS5fFKlVqjXtdpahZ4PW-M2bY2ms4W63Nh1Ol36ibTD38Gi0WiJ5Op8WXHOT-MInbE30WJt2udtjtd5Wq0Tq4CMUSRuZDpYrRljo25g11adwPb1v4DhHCcZwXFcVbLjiq7epuDgpmKwK7t%20MBmoiOztNAGBOgmZ4tvOhizq2TS7PsQG8O2dCdtQ1EAPS0Qg9QwPiVICk48xjKC6TAOWjIOHwBQofBArcLIuj0NaBiqF6tCsbgDgQL6KYQF4ok6OwlG5JRhScTsIn2ExrjWicXiGGuckKUp5IqdwJmadpQl6bgomRDExn%20GZdAWYpwDKapdnSFpgm6Q%20T5qeY9CUY5oUwC5hkSXABnsUE3iRf0IWPrFSXRAlzjtkAA)